# Comment with `code` renders way out of container

Tags: bug, design, comments

Dont know if this is a well known issue for some older comments (after the change to highlight.js), but have not seen this before myself :

[image]

The comment in question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061801/set-column-width-when-exporting-to-pdf-when-using-datatables-net/34065443#34065443). Absolutely nothing is wrong, except it does not look nice :)

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine, yes, well. It was merely a "report" than an actual question. Yes, but I must say, the bug occured in **latest chrome 100** (Ubuntu), in Firefox (did not think about checking out) it looks OK! (as in the link you refer to)

Comment: I also repro in Chrome. Unfortunately, this is quite normal. No one on the Stack Overflow front-end design team appears to know how to reliably keep content from overflowing its container. We see these bugs all over the place, due to inline code formatting, long unbroken strings of text (e.g., URLs), etc. We will have to reset the "Days since a container utterly failed to contain its content" counter back to 0. The reports of observed bugs are, of course, appreciated by those of us who cannot actually fix the problem.

Comment: @CodyGray, Yeah, sorry - and dont throw good money after bad :) Think I have been there myself. Sometimes we must just accept how the universe works :)

Comment: *"Absolutely nothing is wrong"* - well, besides the fact that comments are being pretty badly abused of course. A code dump in a comment and a comment that is essentially a different question.

Comment: @CodyGray, if you change `white-space: pre-wrap;` to `white-space: initial;` it works in Chrome 100.x like in FF.  I have never seen a real use-case for `pre-wrap` anyway, typically a XY-issue; I guess it have something to do with the earlier syntax highlightning, and that prewrap-"tweak" now breaks the entire idea after the switch to highlight.js. But it *is* doable to get it "right looking" just by changing that setting in developer tools, dont know if it is the right solution.